# Combine 2 Column and only show text only from them in SSIS

Tags: sql, database, ssis, expression

Can someone help me with my problem
1. my problem is combining 2 column and choose only Text from them
, this is a sample view of my column
i
[Column Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiuZx.png)

as you can see there some text and number in second column, how can i get text only from them?

2. where i can get complete function SSIS expression?

thank's before

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is in a script transformation with a regular expression.

Found this code [here](http://pragmaticworks.com/Training/Resources/Cheat-Sheets/SSIS-Expression-Cheat-Sheet), and modified it to remove numeric characters:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Overrides Sub Input()_ProcessInputRows(ByVal Row As Input()Buffer)
     If Row.ColumnName_IsNull = False Or Row.ColumnName = "" Then
            Dim pattern As String = String.Empty
            Dim r As Regex = Nothing
            pattern = "[0-9]"
            r = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)
            Row.ColumnName = Regex.Replace(Row.ColumnName, pattern, "")
       End If 
End Sub
```